# C++ using getArea() and accessing an array to work out area of circle

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, geometry, member-functions

I need some help with the following problem which is to work out the areas of each circle within an array using the getArea() method. How do I go about accessing an array and then working out the area of the circle using Circle::getArea() member function.

Main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#include "Circle.h"
#include "Random.h"

int main()
{
    // Array 1, below section is to populate the array with random 
    // radius number within lower and upper range
    int CircleArrayOne [5];
    const int NUM = 5;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int x = 0; x < NUM; ++x)
    {
        CircleArrayOne[x] = Random::random(1, 40); // assumed 0 and 40 as the bounds
    }

    // output the radius of each circle
    cout << "Below is the radius each of the five circles in the second array. " << endl;

    // below is to output the radius in the array
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) 
    {
        cout << CircleArrayOne[i] << endl;
    }

    // Here I want to access the array to work out the area using 
    // float Circl::getArea()

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

float Circle::getArea()
{
    double PI = 3.14;
    return (PI * (Radius*Radius));
}

float Circle::getRadius()
{
    return Radius;
}

int Random::random(int lower, int upper)
{
    int range = upper - lower + 1;
    return (rand() % range + lower);
}
```

Circle.h file

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Circle 
{
private:
    float Radius;

public:
    Circle(); // initialised radius to 0
    Circle(float r); // accepts an argument and assign its value to the radius attribute
    void setRadius(float r); // sets radius to a value provided by its radius parameter (r)
    float getRadius(); // returns the radius of a circle
    float getArea(); // calculates and returns the areas of its circle
};
```

Thanks.
Much help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have any `Circle`s to call `getArea()` on. Which circles do you want the area of? I fully understand that you're new to C++ and you're looking for help, but I think this would be a good point to sit down and read some information on how C++ works. You need to learn something about what a class is, and how to call methods, so that you can understand what's going on here. As is, this question doesn't give enough information on how to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you just have the random radius for circles but do not have `Circle` objects. So, first create circle objects.

```
Circle obj[5];   // Create 5 objects default constructed.
```

Now set each object radius using `setRadius` and call area on each object.